# Pydantic refusing a model that clearly has an annotation

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a clearly annotated pydantic model:

```
class CurrencyCode(TripleApiModel, RootModel[str]):
    """3-character ISO-4217 currency code"""

    root: Annotated[
        str,
        Field(
            "USD",
            description="3-character ISO-4217 currency code",
            examples=["USD"],
            max_length=3,
            min_length=3,
            pattern=r"^[A-Z]{3}$",
        ),
    ]
```

But when I use the model in another class as a type, I get an error.

```
class MyTestModel(BaseModel):
    currency_code: CurrencyCode
```

```
E   pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: A non-annotated attribute was detected: `currency_code = <class 'api_models.models.CurrencyCode'>`. All model fields require a type annotation; if `currency_code` is not meant to be a field, you may be able to resolve this error by annotating it as a `ClassVar` or updating `model_config['ignored_types']`.
E
E   For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/u/model-field-missing-annotation
```

I have followed the instructions at the link provided by the error, but none of the suggestions eliminate the error.

How can I use my bespoke class as a type for pydantic?

Comment: The error message looks as if you had written `currency_code = CurrencyCode` instead of `currency_code: CurrencyCode`.